# Unit test for a mortgage calculator function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I've written this function that calculates payment on mortgage based on the cost of the house, down payment, mortgage period (term of loan), and annual interest rate. I want to test the `calculatePayment` function to make sure that the output is correct. I've chosen Jest, but any other testing tools work. How do I write a test for this function?

```
function calculatePayment() {

    var houseCost = parseFloat(document.getElementById("houseCost").value);
    var downPayment = parseFloat(document.getElementById("downPayment").value);

    var termOfLoan = parseFloat(document.getElementById("termOfLoan").value);

    var annualInterestRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("annualInterestRate").value);
    var principal = houseCost - downPayment;
    var percentageRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;
    var lengthOfLoan = 12 * termOfLoan;
    var monthlyPayment = (principal * percentageRate) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + percentageRate) , lengthOfLoan * -1)));
    monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("payment").value = monthlyPayment;

};
```

Also, if there is a better way to refactor this I'd appreciate that

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to write a unit test for this function?

Comment: Start with a small refactor. Pass the table values into the function instead of pulling it directly from the html. The output should be returned instead of writing to the html. That will make your calculation testable without the html dependency.

Comment: Can you show what you mean?

Comment: Yes, `function calculatePayment(cost, down, term, rate) { ... return montlyPayment; }`.

Comment: sorry, I'm still struggling to refactor. I'd love the whole example so I can break it down and understand.

Answer (score 1):

An unit test tests units. right now you have one complete function.

Split up your function in subfunctions and tests those and the combined effects.

Then you can really test your units.

This is just a very very basic example. Use your unit test suite to the max, make sure you also test for exeptions(what if someone inputs fizzlefup instead of a number for example).

```js
function getFloatFromInput(inputId) {
   return parseFloat(document.getElementById(inputId).value);
}
function getHouseCost() {
    return getFloatFromInput("houseCost");
}
function getDownPayment() {
    return getFloatFromInput("downPayment");
}
function getTermOfLoan() {
    return getFloatFromInput("termOfLoan");
}
function getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return getFloatFromInput("annualInterestRate");
}
function calculatePrincipal(houseCost, downPayment) {
    return houseCost - downPayment;
}
function calculatePercentageRate(annualInterestRate) {
    return annualInterestRate / 1200;
}
function calculateLengthOfloan(termOfLoan) {
    return 12 * termOfLoan;
}
function calculateMonthlyPayment(principal, percentageRate, lengthOfLoan) {
    return ((principal * percentageRate) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + percentageRate) , lengthOfLoan * -1)))).toFixed(2);
}

function calculatePayment() {

    var houseCost = getHouseCost();
    var downPayment = getDownPayment();

    var termOfLoan = getTermOfLoan();

    var annualInterestRate = getAnnualInterestRate();
    var principal = calculatePrincipal(houseCost, downPayment);
    var percentageRate = calculatePercentageRate(annualInterestRate);
    var lengthOfLoan = calculateLengthOfloan(termOfLoan);
    var monthlyPayment = calculateMonthlyPayment(principal, percentageRate, lengthOfLoan);
    document.getElementById("payment").value = monthlyPayment;
};

function test() {
    var assertEquals = function(expected, actual) {
      if(expected === actual) {
        console.log(".");
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Expecting ' + expected +' received '+ actual);
    }
    var tests = [];
    tests.push(function() {
        document.getElementById('houseCost').value = 1;
        var value = getFloatFromInput('houseCost');
        assertEquals(parseFloat("1"),value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        document.getElementById('houseCost').value = 1;
        var value = getHouseCost();
        assertEquals(parseFloat("1"),value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        document.getElementById('downPayment').value = 1;
        var value = getDownPayment();
        assertEquals(parseFloat("1"),value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        document.getElementById('termOfLoan').value = 1;
        var value = getTermOfLoan();
        assertEquals(parseFloat("1"),value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        document.getElementById('annualInterestRate').value = 1;
        var value = getAnnualInterestRate();
        assertEquals(parseFloat("1"),value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        var value = calculatePrincipal(10.5, 5.3);
        assertEquals(5.2, value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        var value = calculatePercentageRate(1200);
        assertEquals(1, value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        var value = calculateMonthlyPayment(1,1,1);
        assertEquals((2.0).toFixed(2), value);
    });
    tests.push(function() {
        document.getElementById('houseCost').value = 1;
        document.getElementById('downPayment').value = 0;
        document.getElementById('termOfLoan').value = 1;
        document.getElementById('annualInterestRate').value = 1;
        calculatePayment()
        assertEquals("0.08",document.getElementById('payment').value);
    });
    for(var c=0;c< tests.length;c++) {
         tests[c]();
    }
    
}
test();
```

```html
<label for="houseCost">houseCost</label><input type="text" id="houseCost"><BR/>
<label for="downPayment">downPayment</label><input type="text" id="downPayment"><BR/>
<label for="termOfLoan">termOfLoan</label><input type="text" id="termOfLoan"><BR/>
<label for="annualInterestRate">annualInterestRate</label><input type="text" id="annualInterestRate"><BR/>
<BR/>
<label for=""></label>
<input type="text" id="payment">
```